# URL com parâmetro fixo e variável

Tags: php, htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Olá, estou tendo dificuldades em acertar o meu arquivo htaccess, sendo que tenho um parâmetro fixo que passo manualmente e um que depende do usuário quando clica e muda o uf, segue o exemplo

```
RewriteRule ^representantes\/(.*)$ representantes.php?i_page=3&uf=$1
```

O parâmetro UF ia depender do usuário quando clica em um link e muda o estado (uf) o i_page seria fixo. A URL ficaria assim:

https://teste.com/representantes

https://teste.com/representantes?uf=SC

**UPDATE**

Tentei algo como

```
RewriteRule ^representantes?uf=(.*)$ representantes.php?i_page=3&uf=$1
```

mais ainda não tive o resultado esperado.

Comment: Ficaria `/representantes?uf=SC` ou `/representantes/SC`? Pode confirmar se colocou certo na pergunta? O texto pede uma coisa, o código mostra outra. Seria essa a dúvida?

Comment: seria assim /representantes?uf=SC, até coloquei o exemplo pra não ter dúvidas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito pesquisar achei uma solução:

```
RewriteRule ^representantes?(.*)$ representantes.php?i_page=3&uf=$1 [QSA,L]
```

essa regra envia o parâmetro fixo e o UF, dai consigo resgatar os valores pelo $_GET. E ainda remove o .php da url deixando mais amigável.